# Creating shared library containing other libraries

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

i've written a class from that i want to create a shared library. But this class uses other libraries. The call that i use to generate the library is of the form
    g++ -fpic -c [necessary *.cpp files] [necessary includes]
Unfortunately this call leads to an error, namely iostream.h: No such file or directory.
But when i build a testfile using the library code it compiles and works properly.

Where might be the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm pretty sure that you should be using `iostream` rather than `iostream.h` so you could try changing that in your source code. E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
```

Secondly, you need to check the include directives on the compilation line, as what you're getting is a compilation error indicating that the preprocessor can't find this file. As you haven't listed either your failed or successful commands here, I can't add much more than that.

Comment: hi, the file including iostream.h comes with a large library. I will have a look if it can be configured in a way to use the standard header. But i don't get why compiling and testing works. I'll post my g++ calls